# How to install bomb in Project IGI Mission 2

Tags: project-igi

I am playing Project IGI 1 and I am on Mission 2.

In this mission I got all the bombs/weapon I need to blast the tank. But when I plant it by clicking the mouse it exploded. I checked out some you tube video and found that I need to install the tank bomb on tank. For that which button on keyboard I need to press.. I am running this on all default controls assigned.

I tried with RIGHT SHIFT , but no luck.

Comment: Any suggestion ? How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is so long ago since I played this game...I'm not sure but it could be that you first had to select the bomb (cycle weapons) and you could then plant it...it's one of the numeric keys if I remember right

Comment: Thanks! I will try to press the numeric keys. Hope that works.

Answer (score 1):

This chunk from a neoseeker walkthrough seems to think it's the 'activate' key.  You're suppose to put the C4 on the 3 missile launchers.

"Leave the building and go left towards the SAM launcher. Use your AK47 to kill the two enemies, then walk up to the SAM launcher and plant the C4 with the "Activate" key. Back to the other SAM launcher and plant C4 on it. Head towards the last SAM vehicle and take out two guys at the bottom of the hill. Keep going and kill a third guy. Four more: in front of the building, next to the Jeep, in the shelter, and next to the crates (in that order). One or two more might come at you. Now go to the SAM, plant C4, and use your map to find the helipad."

Comment: I have planned the bomb on the tank but how would I explode it?

Comment: I don't think you explode them, you just plant them and get to the helipad.

Answer (score 0):

get the chargers from the warehouse and go to the SAM launchers. once you get a symbol indicating that the charge is ready to be placed, press the button you do for opening doors or picking the locks. (left shift in my case). you need to hold the button until you get a message showing that the charge is placed successfully. repeat the procedure for the remaining two SAM launchers.